# Is there any app similar to Facebook that you can install on your own server?

Tags: web-applications

Is there any app similar to Facebook that you can install on your own server?

Like a community app where users can create their own account and post messages, blogs, photos, add friends, etc.

Except, it can't be a hosted solution.  It would have to be installable on a private server or intranet.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at Diaspora (https://joindiaspora.com/)

Comment: Was going to suggest it, but +1 to you since you already have!

Answer (score 2):

I recommend [BuddyPress.](http://buddypress.org/) It's a free, open source, extendable, well maintained extension to WordPress that provides Facebook-style features on a self-hosted setup.

The [download instructions are here.](http://buddypress.org/download/)

Answer (score 1):

[Oxwall](http://www.oxwall.org/) and [Elgg](http://www.elgg.org/) are both open source and free, so you can self-host.

Answer (score 1):

[Dolphin](http://www.boonex.com/dolphin)